# Android push notification without Google service

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am from Apple world, so I don't have much experience with Android.

But what I am looking is a way that Android devices receive push notification, without using any third party servers. Notification need to be standard Android notification (look and feel)

The reason I need this is, because I would need this in a room that does not have access to outer world. (can't connect to any server) But I have my own WiFi so users can receive push notification from my server via my wifi.

I know that on iOS this is not possible, what about Android?

Comment: In that case you should take a look at background services

Comment: Consider looking for a push notification product that can be hosted on-premises. Pushy (https://pushy.me) does just that and does not depend on Google Play Services, which means it will work within your closed Wi-Fi network. Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it is possible using `Service` left running in system (background) after app exit. some samples [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), you should be interested in `START_STICKY` flag

you have to keep some connection (socket?) or interval requesting (not so well, but possible) inside your `Service`. Google Services (including Firebase) does that by itself and "redeliver" received push messages to properly declared (in manifest) app