# Android push notification without firebase

Tags: android

I want to **send android** push notification to the selected user **without using** gcm or firebase. The application is already built without firebase. Now I need to integrate push notification too.

Question:

- How it's possible without firebase?

Actually I want a feature that, when an admin update the value in the one field in database table of particular user, the that user will get a push notification regarding the update. How it is possible?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid firebase? You don't need to rebuild your backend on firebase (with firebase database). Just use Firebase Notifications part from your backend.

Comment: It's definitely possible -- you don't have to use Firebase to deliver push notifications. You can roll out your own notification solution or consider a paid product such as Pushy (https://pushy.me/) which does not rely on Firebase Cloud Messaging. Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.

Comment: This is a good question because we can't rely on others services, an account termination by accident would stop push notification.

Comment: @EladNava,I read the documentation of Pushy, Its well written, but why Pushy needs WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to store the token , the private folder is enough,  isn't it?

Comment: Hi @ENSATE, please note that the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is optional but recommended for persisting device tokens in the external storage so that our SDK can keep track of each device's unique token for when your app is reinstalled on that same device. If this permission is not requested by your app, our SDK will persist the device token only within the SharedPreferences which are cleared when your app is uninstalled. This may cause duplicate billing for the same device when your app is reinstalled as we have no other way of identifying the previous device token after app reinstall.

Comment: @EladNava, I got it , thanks!

Comment: @Gudin  Question of the user is totally legit. For those asking "why not firebase?"... Well, nobody give you nothing for free. As long as your application will grow you will need to pay them...A lot! Do you want an example? Use the google maps API And come back here when you receive a 14k invoice. I wouldn't base my business with 3rd party services without having a Plan B. The same concept regards the magic world of AWS. I always prefer dedicated servers. Probably my company wont grow like bigs, but at least it won't depend by their business. Plans based on traffic sucks.

Comment: @MarcelloKad this is different. You cannot send a notification to iOS without using Apple Push Notification Service, or to Android without using FCM/GCM. All other services/implementations are using these services underneath. Only half-solution is from atlascoder below, but it is flawed.

Comment: @Gudin Some Android devices - such as cheap tablets for kiosk style applications - come without Google Play Services.

Comment: As do many Chinese Android devices. I'm not sure Amazon Fire devices have them either.

Comment: One reason to avoid Firebase is that it is Blocked on some countries like China and Iran. one method is to proxy Firebase through your own server back end, then its should be fine. Pushy.me is an alternative that does work in China though...

Comment: @MarcelloKad isn't firebase push notification totally free?

Answer (score 36):

The way is to create custom Service https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html , which is holding connection via socket or polling some remote server with intervals.

But, I suggest that Firebase service is more advanced and optimized in battery consumption and, particularly, in utilizing the sleep mode. It's not trivial to make a service which will have fast response and CPU consumption. I think that a custom service development will lead to native (C++) coding of networking routines libs.

Also, take into account that Firebase provides own Authentication service with ability to seamless convert your anonymous user to registered. There is a lot of pros of Firebase services. And cons are: your users have to install Google Play Services, if your app will grow - you will pay to Firebase.

Look here [Android push notification without Google service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786743/android-push-notification-without-google-service)

Comment: XMPP is ideal to this purpose. See this: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0357.html

Comment: @ImamBux , I suppose that Firebase uses exactly XMPP))

Comment: I meant the custom XMPP Server, Client and it's libraries for Android. This way you can have your own Push Notification Service.

Comment: @ImamBux, when I did integration of XMPP into Android application - I remember I had not found working libs for Android with the XEP-0357 feature. Could you share please, what lib provide working functionality at this time?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Nowadays OS will kill your service real quick. Some chinese brands will even kill foreground services.

Comment: @atlascoder Google Play Services itself, nowadays, is the main battery hog.

Comment: @BahramArdalan, what I did want to say is that implementation of efficient Service is not a trivial task. Especially with wide variety of Android versions and phones..

Comment: Hey, @elad-nava, why have you added an advertising to my answer? I don't know what the Pushy is! Why wouldn't you write your own answer?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible using VAPID authentication.

Google for VAPID and you will find a very tortuous road that could lead to the answer you are looking for.

Comment: funny name. sounds like Count Dracula saying "Rapid."

Comment: yeah.. or elmer fudd :D

Comment: While using VAPID you may not need to register on Google Cloud/Firebase and create API KEY, but under the hood you will be using Firebase with Web Push if you are using a Chrome browser!
Check out this answer to know more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48684217/2789895

Answer (score 7):

another option is [Gotify](https://gotify.net/). Gotify is self-hosted open source notification solution that you can use it to send push notification to your android app without need of Firebase.

with help of [UnifiedPush](https://unifiedpush.org/) you can receive push notifications in your android app.

you can easily host Gotify server on Docker and use [it's Api](https://gotify.net/api-docs) or cli,... to send notifications.

here is a good article about Gotify: https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2020/230/Gotify

Comment: Hi. I just bumped into this answer. Can Onesignal be a self hosted solution ? My question is here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74896610/self-hosted-push-notification-service. I'm looking for a solution that does not rely on Firebase and has a self hosted server. Can Onesignal do the needful (If it is open source)