# Push Notifications in Oreo

Tags: android

Since Android Oreo implemented restrictions on background services, how do you implement Push Notifications without FCM? Firebase provides `FirebaseMessagingService` to handle receiving push notifications when the app is in the background, but what's the way of doing that without Firebase? Before Oreo, you could do that in background service, but now an app can't really start a background service.

It got me interested because I was reading about Facebook Messenger, and they use MQTT for push notifications, but where do they listen to subscribed topics when the app is not in the foreground?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android push notification without firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511475/android-push-notification-without-firebase)

Comment: @Gelo that answer suggest using a background service, which is what you can't do on Oreo anymore

Comment: Facebook Messenger, along with every other messaging app (Whatsapp, Signal, etc), all use FCM while in the background. They can certainly use other options while in the foreground though.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Oh, the facebook's post about using MQTT was from 2011, just notices that, so they switch over, ok.