# Push Notification from local server

Tags: android, push-notification

I am building my first Android app and need to know how I could use push notification.

My project is a home alarm system and also I have built my own local web server. Now I want to push a notification from my server to my Android app when an alarm appears in my server.

Currently my garage doors use the MyQ app and when the garage door opens or closes I get a notification on my phone, I want to implement the same thing in my app.

I've been reading about the **[Google Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)** but it seems exceeding my need.

Answer (score 1):

If you need push notification on your cell phone then you definitely need to integrate your app with Google Firebase. (or at least that's the right way of doing it).

Alternatively, there is something called as local notifications & background process in Android you could do long polling to check if the garage door is open (probably every 2 mins or something). However, I don't recommend that as it can drain your mobile battery.

Also I recommend using [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) as oppose to using Native Android. As there are some pre-built libraries for android and Google Firebase integration.

Take a look at this Youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TSm2YGBT1s

Answer (score 0):

Ouh, maybe thats a little bit too much for starting with android - nevertheless I want to help you.

You need a communication protocol between your server and your phone (i.e. Firebase as you mentioned or Websockets).

If your server sends a message to you client (your phone) you have to create a notification. ([Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)). That's the theoretical part. You will also stumble across a lot of 
challenges with 
asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase might actually be the simplest option. You could build your own web socket service too, but that would probably be more than you need. See this previous question for more options: [Android push notification without firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511475/android-push-notification-without-firebase/43682770)

Answer (score 0):

Android has some services that communicate with firebase to receive notifications.

You'll need to implement a service on top of your web server (using backend languages such as Python, Node.js, PHP,...) so it can send notifications when an event happened (like the door closed) witch isn't a simple way for a beginner.

then your web server sends a message to firebase and tells it to send a notification to my client.

so I highly recommend using firebase because of the simplicity of usage. otherwise, you should implement a separate service on your android phone to get the notification (if you want to run it locally) also as explained do the backend side.

Comment: Ahhh, so if I am understanding correctly I will send an HTTP request from my microcontroller webserver to Firebase then Firebase will send a notification (based on the event) to my app on my phone where a notification event is waiting in the background.  With all the reading I've done on Firebase I haven't found anything that describes notifications in this manner, all I have seen are notifications that are sent by directly interacting with the Firebase UI.  I will look deeper into the documentation.

Comment: also, there is a protocol named MQTT to do this. checkout [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/about-the-mqtt-protocol-for-iot-on-android-efb4973577b) for more information.