# How to send push notifications with node and capacitor

Tags: node.js, angular, capacitor

I have `Angular` application with `Capacitor` (without `Ionic`) and I need to send push notifications to the user app from `Node.js` backend. How would I do that? Any article, source or example would be much appreciable?

Here is `capacitor.config.ts` file

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx',
  appName: 'ABC',
  webDir: 'dist/abc',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  plugins: {
    PushNotifications: {
      presentationOptions: ["badge", "sound", "alert"],
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

I have seen many artcles etc. on push notifications with `Capacitor` and `Firebase` but couldn't find a single source on my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and easiest solution so far is to implement it with firebase. There are primarily two parts to this entire setup

- Configure Capacitor and Firebase to be able to receive notifications

For this I suggest you follow [this tutorial](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase) word by word.

- Code the nodejs implementation to send push notifications from the server

For this, follow the firebase official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)

As a reference, here is how you can handle the nodejs part, this triggers push notifications successfully.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: <Your-Firebase-DB-URL>
});

async function sendNotification(tokens, title, body, data = {}) {
    message = {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
        },
        data: data
    }
    options = {
        priority: 'high'
    }
    result = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, message, options)
    return result;
}

module.exports = { sendNotification };
```

Comment: Thank you for this but can you please tell any source which directly deals with node.js instead including firebase between node and capacitor?

Comment: I don't believe that someone has approached implementing it that way.. Theoretically, it is possible.. but the complexities of setting it all up manually and overburdening the server with this extra task is what makes people use services like firebase.. Your node server will have to talk to APNS and Google.. For APNS refer this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/send-push-notification-through-apns-using-node-js-7427a01662a2 but for Android, you will have to again fallback to FCM.. refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511475/android-push-notification-without-firebase