# What do I need to implement to have notifications in my android app when its not running?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I have android app which is connected to a background channel and publishes notification to the device when a new event triggers in the channel , And it works fine when my app is in foreground .
But it does not work when the app is not running.
How to achieve that?
I am not using Firebase in either android or backend,
in backend its simply a JS channel which pushes updates to the channel which are to be caught by the clients connected to the channel- how to do that?

Can I use WorkManager ? but it is for jobs like->

> Deferrable, because you don’t need it to happen immediately, and in
>   fact might want to wait for some constraints to be met (such as
>   waiting for a network connection)

As I dont use FCM , how do I achieve the background notification in android?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android push notification without Google service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786743/android-push-notification-without-google-service)